# How to beatify my URL with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site that contains only two files. The first file is the `index.php` and the second one is the `index_el.php`.

What I am looking to do is to force these two files to accessible with rewrited url.

More specific, I like when somebody enter the url `http://www.site.ext/index.php` to be redirected on `http://www.site.ext/` and when somebody enter the url `http://www.site.ext/index_el.php` to be redirected on `http://www.site.ext/el`

Currently I have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^index_el\.php$ /el/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

but, while the `index.php` redirect the user to `/` the `index_el.php` redirect the user on `/el/` and the server returns a `404` error.

Can somybody help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index_?)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^index /%1 [R=301,L,NE,NC]

RewriteRule ^el/? /index_el.php [L,NC]
```